# Display Union of 2 sets in C#

Tags: c#, union

I have a code in C# where I ask the user for the number of sets he wants to create and then enter elements in those sets. From those sets, he selects 2 sets and displays a union of the selected sets.

In the below code, the elements in the sets are not getting added to _items and the Union is not displayed.

Thanks for any help.

```
namespace Union
{

  class Program
  {
    static List<SortedSet<string>> _items = new List<SortedSet<string>>();
    static SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i, j, a, b;
        string k;
        Console.WriteLine("\n Enter the number of set to be used: ");
        i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter first element in set {0}:", j);
                k = Console.ReadLine();
                if (k != "stop")
                    set.Add(k);
            } while (k != "stop");
            _items.Add(set);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter index of 1st set  of union:{0}");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter index of 2nd set  of union:{0}");
        c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        DisplayUnion(a, b);
    }

    public static void DisplayUnion(int a, int b)
    {
        SortedSet<string> set1 = _items[a];
        SortedSet<string> set2 = _items[b];
        set1.UnionWith(set2);
        Console.WriteLine(set1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully edited my answer by modifiing `Main()` and `DisplayUnion(int a, int b)` methods to achieve better representation and include border case scenarios.
`Main()` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, j, a, b;
    string k;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of sets to be used: ");
    i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
        var index = 0;
        do
        {
            index++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Enter {index} element in set {j}:");
            k = Console.ReadLine();
            if (k != "stop")
                set.Add(k);
        } while (k != "stop");
        _items.Add(set);
    }

    if (_items.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have no sets to union.");
        return;
    }

    if (_items.Count == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Union of only set is: " + string.Join("", _items[0]));

        return;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter index of 1st set  of union:{0}");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (a < _items.Count)
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Set {a} does not exists.");
    }

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter index of 2nd set  of union:{0}");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (b < _items.Count)
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Set {b} does not exists.");
    }
```

}

`DisplayUnion(int a, int b)` method:

```
public static void DisplayUnion(int a, int b)
{

    SortedSet<string> set1 = _items[a];
    SortedSet<string> set2 = _items[b];
    set1.UnionWith(set2);
    Console.WriteLine($"Union of set {a + 1} with set {b + 1} is: " + string.Join("", set1));
}
```

You receive outOfRangeException because you enter invalid index for a set without checking anywhere that it's actually invalid.I solved that by adding adding two `while cycles`. 
Also I added two `if statements` for border cases when sets are 0 or 1.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But I am still getting an error in _items[a] that argument out of range exception was unhandled...

Comment: The reason for this is that you do not check for invalid index anywhere. See the edit.